# Map area hover behaving strangely

Tags: html, css, dictionary, hover, css-position

I am displaying a `<div>` called `#mastermap` which contains several slots.

These slots are represented by images which are set at specific coordinates using absolute positioning and `margin-top` + `margin-left`.

Each image is followed by a `<map>` and `<area>` which allows me to hyperlink the diamond-shaped slots to a placeholder URL.

Below my map is a `#tooltip-bar` section which displays default information when no slot is hovered.

However, when a slot is hovered, its own `.tooltip` is displayed over the `#tooltip-bar` section.

**Here are the issues :**

If I select my `.tooltip` with `#mastermap map:hover > .tooltip`, using the `>` parent-child combinator, my tooltips display correctly when the areas are hovered, but they don't disappear when the mouse leaves the area. The tooltip only changes if I hover over a slot that comes later in the code, but not if it comes earlier. It seems that I have to leave the entire `#mastermap` area in order to "reset" the hover.

If instead I choose to use `#mastermap area:hover ~ .tooltip {` with the `~` or `+` sibling combinators, the tooltips come on and off, which cancels the previous problem, but introduces another.

**I have posted the full code here : http://cssdesk.com/qe4bh**

I am running all this on Firefox and have not yet tested the code on any other browser.

I imagine that there may be solutions to my problem using JavaScript, but I have not yet introduced myself to this language, and am ideally looking for a CSS/HTML fix for now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue was much simpler than I thought.

It was simply a problem of positioning, where my `.tooltip` used `position:relative`, which meant it was displaced upon `map:hover`. Because of this, the `map` was no longer hovered, causing a loop.

The fix was to simply replace `position:relative` by `position:absolute`.

This is demonstrated here : http://cssdesk.com/SwGad